# Assemble / Handlebars Sort Order

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I created a simple dynamic navigation using the example from the the Assemble FAQs

```
{{#each pages }}
  {{#is data.section "main"}}
    <li{{#is ../../page.dest this.dest}} class="active"{{/is}}>
      <a href="{{relative ../../page.dest this.dest}}">{{data.menutitle}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/is}}
{{/each}}
```

How does one achieve sort-order? Right now the links seem to be in random order. They seem to be in the alpha-order of the page alias (index.html).

They should be:

`Index 
Products
Find Us`

but what's rendered is:

`Find Us
Index 
Products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the [Assemble documentation](http://assemble.io/docs/Collections.html) that has a section on using `withSort`.

I'd use something like:

```
{{#withSort pages data.sortOrder}}
    {{#is data.section "main"}}
        <li{{#is ../../page.dest this.dest}} class="active"{{/is}}>
            <a href="{{relative ../../page.dest this.dest}}">{{data.menutitle}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/is}}
{{/withSort}}
```

Where sortOrder is defined at page level, for example having this in your page templates:

```
---
title: Index
sortOrder: 0
---
```

etc.

Comment: I tried these options to no avail..

    {{#withSort pages "data.sortOrder"}}
           {{#is data.section "main"}}
            <li{{#is ../../page.dest this.dest}} class="active"{{/is}}>
                                          <a href="{{relative ../../page.dest this.dest}}">{{data.menutitle}}</a>
                                      </li>
           {{/is}}
          {{/withSort}}


layout: home.hbs
title: What is ZMIX?
section: main
sortOrder: a-000

Help?